# Characterize the level sets of quadratic forms

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

Consider a quadratic function given by
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^{\text{T}}Ax + c^{\text{T}}x + d, 
$$
where $A$ is an $n \times n$ symmetric matrix, $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $d \in \mathbb{R}$.

Now I want to characterize the level sets or contours of $f$ in dependence whether $A$ is positive definite ($A \succ 0$), positive semidefinite ($A \succeq 0$), negative indefinite ($A \prec 0$), negative semidefinite ($A \preceq 0$) or indefinite. The level sets are given by

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}(a) = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \mid f(x) = a \},
\end{equation}

where $a \in \mathbb{R}$.
Here is my approach. Let us first compute the gradient of $f$, which is given by
$$
\nabla f(x) = Ax + c.
$$
Now suppose $A$ is invertible we get

$$
\nabla f(x) = 0 \iff x = - A^{-1}c
$$

Now we can rewrite $f$ as follows
$$
f(x) = \left(x - \hat{x} \right)^{\text{T}} A \left(x - \hat{x} \right) - \frac{1}{2}c^{\text{T}}A^{-1}c + d,
$$
where $\hat{x} := - A^{-1}c$. Now I think $\left(x - \hat{x} \right)^{\text{T}} A \left(x - \hat{x} \right)$ defines me an ellipsoid if $A$ is positive semidefinite. But what about the other terms? If I write down the level sets I get

$$
\mathcal{L}(a) = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \mid f(x) = a \} = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \mid \left(x - \hat{x} \right)^{\text{T}} A \left(x - \hat{x} \right) = a + \frac{1}{2}c^{\text{T}}A^{-1}c - d\}.
$$

Does for example
$$
\left(x - \hat{x} \right)^{\text{T}} A \left(x - \hat{x} \right) = a + \frac{1}{2}c^{\text{T}}A^{-1}c - d
$$
defines me an ellipse if $A$ is positive definite? What is the interpretation of the righthand side term $a + \frac{1}{2}c^{\text{T}}A^{-1}c - d$?

I am thankful for every help!

Comment: Level sets are quadrics, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadric

Comment: if $f$ is a quadratic form then $f\big(\alpha\cdot x\big) = \vert \alpha\vert^2 \cdot f\big(x\big)$ which does not apply to $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^{\text{T}}Ax + c^{\text{T}}x + d$

Comment: I'm sorry. I mean $f$ is a quadratic function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The level sets of $f$ are bounded if and only if $A$ is positive definite or negative definite.

If $A$ is positive definite or negative definite then level sets of $f$ are ellipsoids (or empty): Let $A=QDQ^T$ with $Q$ orthogonal. Set $y:=Q^T(x-\hat x)$.
Then using this in the equation in the OP
$$
y^TDy = (x-\hat x)A(x-\hat x) = const.
$$
This is nothing else than an equation of the type
$$
\sum_i d_i y_i^2 = const,
$$
hence the set of all such $y$ is an ellipsoid. Then also the corresponding level set is an ellipsoid.

Assume one level set of $f$ is unbounded. Then there is a sequence $(x_n)$ with $\|x_n\|\to \infty$ such that
$$
\frac12 x_n^TAx_n + c^Tx_n + d = a.
$$
The normalized sequence $\frac1{\|x_n\|}x_n$ has a subsequence that converges to some unit vector $x$.

Dividing the equation above by $\|x_n\|^2$ and passing to the limit along the subsequence yields
$$
\frac12 x^TAx=0.
$$
Hence, $A$ is neither positive nor negative definite.

Comment: Why are the levels set ellipsoids if $A$ is positive definite or  negative definite? How can I see this?